# Python Rock Paper Scissors

Tags: python, function

I am having trouble with this part of my assignment. I have to declare a winner of the game and then input into a function. Once I have entered all the `if` statements I then have to create a function `def playGame()`. This has to include:

```
showRules()
user = getUserChoice()
computer = getComputerChoice()
declareWinner(user, computer)

def playGame():
    showRules()
    user = getUserChoice()
    computer = getComputerChoice()
    declareWinner(user, computer)

print("**** Rock-Paper-Scissors ****")

#Display game rules
def showRules():
    print("Rules: Each player chooses either Rock, Paper, or Scissors.")
    print("\tThe winner is determined by the following rules:")
    print("\t\tScissors cuts Paper   --> Scissors wins")
    print("\t\tPaper covers Rock     --> Paper wins")
    print("\t\tRock smashes Scissors --> Rock Wins")


#User selection
def getUserChoice():
    choice = (input("Make your selection (Rock, Paper, or Scissors). ")).lower()
    return choice

#obtain computer input
def getComputerChoice():
    import random
    rnum = random.randint(1,3)
    if rnum == 1:
        print("The computer has chosen Rock.")
    if rnum == 2:
        print("The computer has chosen Paper.")
    if rnum == 3:
        print("The computer has chosen Scissors.")
    return rnum

#Declare winner
def declareWinner(user, rnum):
    print("\n\nuser: ", user)
    print("rnum: ", rnum)    

    if ((user == "rock") and (rnum == 3)):
        print("Rock smashes Scissors --> Player wins!")    

    if ((user == "paper") and (rnum == 1)):
        print("Paper covers Rock --> Player wins!")

    if ((user == "Scissors") and (rnum == 2)):
        print("Scissors cuts Paper --> Player wins!")
```

Below is the output I get when I run the program:

```
**** Rock-Paper-Scissors ****
playGame()
Rules: Each player chooses either Rock, Paper, or Scissors.
    The winner is determined by the following rules:
        Scissors cuts Paper   --> Scissors wins
        Paper covers Rock     --> Paper wins
        Rock smashes Scissors --> Rock Wins
Make your selection (Rock, Paper, or Scissors). ROCk
The computer has chosen Rock.


user:  rock
rnum:  1
```

I need the output to look like this:

```
Rules: Each player chooses either Rock, Paper, or Scissors.
    The winner is determined by the following rules:
        Scissors cuts Paper   --> Scissors wins
        Paper covers Rock     --> Paper wins
        Rock smashes Scissors --> Rock Wins
Make your selection (Rock, Paper, or Scissors). Paper

The computer has chosen Paper.

Paper covers Rock --> Player wins!
```

Please help.

I'm sure there are more efficient ways of doing this. At this point in the course we are working with functions and I need to know how to incorporate them to make the program function work properly.

Comment: In both of your output examples, computer chooses the same as player. In the 'correct' example, rock comes out of nowhere having both chosen paper. Assume typo.

Answer (score 2):

You only have 3 `if` statements - your program only knows what to do in these scenarios:

```
if ((user == "rock") and (rnum == 3)):
if ((user == "paper") and (rnum == 1)):
if ((user == "Scissors") and (rnum == 2)):
```

You have to include something for draws, for winning, and for losing

```
if ((user == "rock") and (rnum == 1)):
    #Whatever you want it to do
if ((user == "rock") and (rnum == 2)):
    #Stuff
if ((user == "rock") and (rnum == 3)):
    #Etc
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could do something like `else: print('No winner that round!')`

Answer (score 1):

Look at your conditions; none of them match what occurred in the sample you gave.  You have no condition for `user == rock` and `rnum == 1`.  That's why none of the `print` statements in your conditionals are being printed.

Answer (score 0):

Either your code is not complete or its missing the case you have chosen.  There is no tie in your code but the outcome shows a tie.

Also i would use `if` and `elif` to mimic "case"  as you would do in other languages and normalize the user input:

```
rock == 1
paper == 2
```

then you can compare them more easily;

```
if user == rnum:
 # print tie message
else:
    if user == 1 and rnum ==2:
     #dosomething
     elif user == 1 and rnum == 3:
     # do something else
```

and so on

Another option would be to nest the if statements

```
if user == rnum:
# print tie
 else:
    if user == 1:
       if rnum == 2:
        #print
        elif rnum == 2:
        #print
    if user == 2:
```

Answer (score 0):

In almost all programming you should think about the possible outcomes and if you handle them all correctly. This is basically what unit tests do; test as many legal and illegal inputs to your units of code so that the code still behaves as expected.

In this case you encountered a classic case of unexpected results, where you input one thing, but didn't get your wanted outcome. If you check your code, and as others have noted, Rock Paper Scissors has 3^2 = 9 possible match ups, and you only define 3 in your code. That leaves 6 missing.

Now, you want to write cases for the other 6 match-ups. You could write a big list of `if` statements (the simple `if user == computer` will solve 3 of the 6 match ups instantly), but I'll give you something else that I think looks much cleaner, expresses intent and is readable, involves no code duplication, and keeps the logic nicely separated. Hope it helps you.

```
DRAW = 0
LOSE = 1
WIN = 2

ROCK = "rock"
PAPER = "paper"
SCISSORS = "scissors"

def winsAgainst(one, other):
    """ Returns true if `one` wins against `other` """
    return ((one == ROCK and other == SCISSORS) or
            (one == PAPER and other == ROCK) or 
            (one == SCISSORS and other == PAPER))

def reasonOfWinning(winner):
    """ A description of WHY the winner actually won """
    if winner == ROCK:
        return "Rock crushes Scissors"
    if winner == PAPER:
        return "Paper covers Rock"
    if winner == SCISSORS:
        return "Scissors cut Paper"

def match(user, computer):
    """ 
    Matches up user and computer and returns who won.

    Both user and computer should be one of ROCK, PAPER or SCISSORS.
    """
    # This handles 3 cases of drawing
    if user == computer:
        return DRAW

    # Handles 3 cases where user wins
    if winsAgainst(user, computer):
        return WIN

    # Handles the last 3, where computer wins.
    else:
        return LOSE

def playGame():
    showRules()
    user = getUserChoice()
    computer = getComputerChoice()

    outcome = match(user, computer)
    if(outcome == DRAW):
        print "Awhh, it's a draw"
    elif(outcome == WIN):
        print "{} --> Player wins!".format(reasonOfWinning(user))
    elif(outcome == LOSE):
        print "{} --> Computer wins!".format(reasonOfWinning(computer))
```